# react load new content based on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have three separate files.

Nav.js

```
var NavItem = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <li><a href="#">{this.props.name}</a></li>
    );
  }
});

var NavList = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var navNodes = this.props.data.map(function(nav) {
      return (
        <NavItem name={nav.name} key={nav.id}></NavItem>
      );
    });
    return (
      <ul className="nav">
        <li className="current"><a href="#"><i className="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i> Lists</a></li>
        {navNodes}
        <li><a href="#"><i className="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Add New Widget List</a></li>
      </ul>
    );
  }
});

var NavBox= React.createClass({
  loadNavsFromServer: function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://server/api/widgetlists/?format=json",
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({data: data});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error("http://server/api/widgetlists/?format=json", status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {data: []};
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.loadNavsFromServer();
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="col-md-2">
        <div className="sidebar content-box" style={{display: "block"}}>
            <NavList data={this.state.data} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = {
    NavBox: NavBox
}
```

Content.js

```
var Widgets = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {data: []};
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://server/api/widgets/?list="xxxx"&format=json',
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({data: data});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error('http://server/api/widgets/?list="xxxx"&format=json', status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="col-md-10">
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col-md-6">
        <div className="content-box-large">
          <div className="panel-body">
              <BootstrapTable data={this.state.data} striped={true}>
                <TableHeaderColumn isKey={true} hidden={true} dataField="id">Widget ID</TableHeaderColumn>
                <TableHeaderColumn dataField="title">Title</TableHeaderColumn>                
                <TableHeaderColumn dataField="username">Username</TableHeaderColumn>
                <TableHeaderColumn dataField="price">Price</TableHeaderColumn>
              </BootstrapTable>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = {
    Widgets: Widgets
}
```

App.js

```
var Navigation = require("./components/Navigation/Navigation");
var Content = require("./components/Content/Content");

ReactDOM.render(
   <Navigation.NavBox/>,
    document.getElementById('navigation')
);

ReactDOM.render(
   <Content.Widgets/>,
    document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Depending on what link is clicked in Nav.js I want it to update the data in Content.js.  NavItem in Nav.js would pass the list name into Content.js (the "xxxx" so that the table would load with the specific data based on that Item.

Comment: You can use an event emitter to communicate between components without a common parent.

Answer (score 2):

As @FakeRainBrigand mentions in his comment, this is a pretty typical use case for some type of event-based pattern like Flux.

https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html

Basically, you want to create some type of singleton data store that keeps track of the list name. Attach a click handler to the `NavItem` component that causes a change to the list name in the store. The store should emit a change event in response to any changes. The `Widgets` component should listen for changes on the store, and when the `Widgets` component hears a change on the store, it should make another AJAX request with the new list item.

Let me know if you have any specific questions about implementation.